# Ubuntu 12.04 boot error, I/O error

Tags: 12.04, boot

Ububtu is failing to boot into the gui. I have tried using boot repair but it failed to work: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5747328

I installed recommended updates yesterday.

Image of error for your reference:

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sam - you appear to have multiple accounts.  Please click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page and request that your accounts are merged.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [HDD Regenerator](http://hdd-regenerator.en.softonic.com/) to solve your problem. See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0QhVIR2gtE) to check how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It might also be that when you were downloading the iso file, there might have been some errors. I would try and download the ubuntu iso again, reinstall, and see if that works. This issue has happened to me before too.